# Problems with custom headers for Thunderbird message filters

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

In Thunderbird 3, I have a couple of message filters set up with Reply-To as the header to filter on. They don't seem to work at all when filtering on the individual message (and I can't see anything in the filter log). However, they do work if I run the filter on the whole folder. I think previous versions had some issues with custom headers too, but I have had this filter working perfectly before.

Comment: You have it checked to run on incoming right?

Comment: Well, it didn't run when the message first came. Hence me trying to run it on the individual message. I can't see why Reply-To would only work on incoming... but then I can't see why it would work on folder but not individual either :S

Comment: Same thing here - trying to add the 'Sender' header; restarted TB; filter won't run neither on message, nor on whole folder - and log doesn't really say which fields are tested ...

Comment: 12+ years and 99 versions later and same problem in Thunderbird 102... filter on "Sender" doesn't work on individual message but works on entire folder.